# How to monitor multiple Azure MySQL PaaS DBs

Tags: mysql, azure, monitoring, paas

I have multiple Azure MySQL PaaS databases running across regions on which alerts have been set.

Are there any way in which I can create a dashboard or run query that can provide the top utilized DBs ?

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Database and Azure SQL Managed Instance offer advanced monitoring and tuning capabilities that leverage artificial intelligence to help you troubleshoot and optimize the performance of your databases and solutions.

you can use Azure Sql Analytics for the monitoring or the Azure monitoring.

[exemple Azure Analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svUea.png)

And for requests to several databases you can create a data factory with your 3 databases (it's a kind of merge) and then you can make a request for several databases

[exemple of data factory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Si1.png)